# If statement contingent on data from 2 cells

Tags: excel-2010

Using Excel 2010 I need a formula that will respond to data in one cell, and differently to data in another.

Cell A1 = Date

Cell A2 = Invoice Dollar Value

Cell A3 = Discount (formula to remove 15% from A2)

Cell A4 = Refund amount

Cell A5 I want to read... if there is a date in A1, then `A2 - A3`, BUT if there is a value in A4 then `A4 - A2` (note, if there is a value in A4, there will not be a value in A2)

I have tried the following...

`=IF(A1<>"",(A2-A3),"",If(A4<>"",A4-A3,""))`

So my goal is to have the spreadsheet calculate Invoice amount minus any discount. And in the same cell calculate refund amount minus any discount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer IF statement isn't quite right. The structure is

`IF(Condition,<execute this when true>,<execute this when false>)`. But you're putting 4 parameters into it.

Try `=IF(A1<>"",(A2-A3),If(A4<>"",A4-A3,""))` instead.

NB: This only checks that cells A1 & A4 have values, not that they are of a specific type, i.e. it it isn't checking that A1 has a date.